# Update active Activity UI with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I have implemented recurring alarms using the following [example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks/)

However, once an alarm "goes off"/is recieved I want to update my `ListView` in the active Activity. I only have one activity with a `ListView`.

How do I execute my update UI method in the main activity class once an alarm is received? How do you call this from `onReceive()` in the `AlarmReceiver` (`extends BroadcastReceiver`) class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to make your AlarmReceiver an inner class of your activity. This way it will have access to all fields and methods of your activity. If you don't use it anywhere else, it might as well be anonymous. 
To make it update your activity only when it's active, register your receiver in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`. Notice the `IntentFilter` specifying intent actions your `BroadcastReceiver` will respond to.

Example:

```
private BroadcastReceiver updateReceiver;

//...

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    updateReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //your list update code here
        }
    };
    IntentFilter updateIntentFilter=new IntentFilter("update");
    registerReceiver(updateReceiver, updateIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (this.updateReceiver!=null)
        unregisterReceiver(updateReceiver);
}
```

If you still want your AlarmReceiver to be a separate class, pass some kind of callback to it during initialization:

```
public interface AlarmReceiverCallback {
    public void onAlarmReceived(Intent intent);
}

//in your AlarmReceiver class:
private AlarmReceiverCallback callback;

public AlarmReceiver(AlarmReceiverCallback callback) {
    this.callback=callback;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    callback.onAlarmReceived(intent);
}
```

Initialization of your `AlarmReceiver` will look the following way:

```
updateReceiver=new AlarmReceiver(new AlarmReceiverCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAlarmReceived(Intent intent) {
        //your list update code here
    }     
});
```

Comment: If I user the first approach how do I set my recurring alarms? I have tried the 'setRecurringAlarm()' from the original link modifying it to set an alarm every 5 seconds. It works with a separate broadcast receiver class. How does it work with an inner class?

Comment: @Santiago When you register your `BroadcastReceiver`, you can pass `IntentFilter` instance specifying actions your receiver will respond to ("update" in my example). So now, when you prepare `Intent` for your alarm, set its action to the same as specified by `IntentFilter` (i.e. "update"), and that should do it.

Comment: thank you! I was unaware of the set action method. It's working now

Comment: .@deville i have been testing this on my phone and unfortunately the alarm is not received during sleep. For example if i set the alarm daily and the device is "awake" i can see the alarm is received and my list is updated. But if i test on my phone and check the app after an hour or so the list is not updated and alarm not received.

Comment: It looks like the alarms don't work in android 2.2. They work perfectly on 2.2+ @deville

Comment: @Santiago maybe the problem is in your device?

Comment: Is it safe to make the Broadcast receiver Singleton or it doesn't matter ?!

Comment: @3amoura difficult to tell without seeing the code, but in general broadcast receivers are not used that way.