# android - send some data to opened activity from broadcast

Tags: android

i have opened activity with disabled button, this activity when it opened automatically sends SMS message(Query Message) to our service provider . (that's the mission of this activity ).

NOW  the trick
i have broadcastreceiver listen to reply of my Query Message  in some conditions i want to Enable button on the already opened activity .

in simple words - i want to enable, the disabled button in activity according of received message in broadcastreceiver while activity opened?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364632/update-active-activity-ui-with-broadcastreceiver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver seesm these questions might have answers already

Comment: try using a background thread to check the reception of the msg and enable the button from a handler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have registered `BroadcastReceiver` in this activity than just use `setEnabled(true)` in `onReceive` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
     button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: the BroadcastReceiver registered in Manifest file , not in the same activity.